# Loading Bootloader into P89V51RD2

Tags: microcontroller

I have two P89V51RD2 microcontrollers, Out of this only one is working fine and in the other one the bootloader is corrupted. How can i replace the corrupted bootloader using working P89V51RD2.

Can i use MOSI, MISO & SCK pins of P89V51RD2 microcontroller ?

Comment: What does the datasheet say?

Comment: How you confirmed that Boot loader is corrupted? IMO, Bootloader goes in ROM and it would be difficult (Read, Impossible) to make changes in that.

Comment: Assuming that it is corrupted, how can i reload that.

Answer (score 1):

You can restore it using a parallel programmer. Here are the steps:

1. Download boot-loader from [FlashMagic website](http://www.flashmagictool.com/assets/resources/P89V51Rx2_Bootloader_Update.zip). & extract it.
2. Load the corresponding HEX file to your programmer software. **Be sure that HEX file is loaded at correct address i.e. `0x10000` else correct it manually**.
3. Overwrite address from `0x10000` to `0x10002` with `43 B1 02` respectively.
4. Burn the customized HEX file to MCU with your programmer.
5. Enjoy Programming! :-)

You can also take a look at [this](http://forum.flashmagictool.com/index.php?topic=3722.msg5016#msg5016).